# Seeing topographical information in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inspector

The Firefox Web Developer's Toolbar had an option under Information to see the topographical information about a page: what's inside of what. Is there any way to see that with Chrome's Dev Tools?

I installed the Web Developer's Toolbar on Chrome but can't see any way to turn the toolbar on. Then I found something from 2013 about Google  disabling toolbars.

So, is there a way to see what elements are inside of what elements with Chrome?

I'm using Chrome 34.0.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "topographical information". Do you need the DOM structure proper (as a tree) or its graphic representation (the page layout)?

Comment: I suppose either approach might work.  I want to be able to see at a glance, for example, that DIVs A and B are siblings inside of DIV C and that DIV C is inside of DIV D.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, Firefox offers a 3D view of the DOM hierarchy, where a child element appears layered on top of its parent element.  When rendered, it is a topological map based on the complexity of the page layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Pendule](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pendule/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi) Chrome extension has a **Topographic View** which works like the Firefox one.

[image: Pendule screenshot]

And about the Web Developer extension in Chrome, after you install it, you'll be able to enable it from chrome://extensions/, it will show a gear icon button at the top right of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

According to William Price's comment, something that was once called "Tilt" in FireFox is meant. We considered doing the same thing, but since it was impossible to correctly display overlapped elements' contents (IIRC, Tilt had the same issue), we abandoned that idea. Instead, we've got the `Layers` panel, which displays compositing layers (see [Layer composition in the chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693961/layer-composition-in-the-chrome-dev-tools)).