# Chrome render layer - creation conditions?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am experiencing slowness with an animation in my website.
After some investigation I found out (via the DevTools timeline tab) that the problem is that the entire page is being re-painted instead of just the animated div.

I checked the "Show composited layer borders" option, and found out that sometimes the animated div is in another render layer.
But I can't find a consistent behavior:

- When the div is not in another layer - the animation is slow.
- When the div is in another layer, sometimes the animation is fast and sometimes it is slow, depending on the presence of other elements in the page (a div with `position:fixed`, a `marquee`, etc). These other elements appear to be totally unrelated to the animated div in the DOM tree but obviously have an effect on the rendering of the page during the animation.

I found a few articles ([1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/), [2](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome), [3](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/introducing-layout-boundaries/), [4](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline), [5](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/the-runtime-performance-checklist/)) that suggest possible ways to "force" Chrome to render an element in another render layer but most of them are old (things might have changed).
Also, they generally don't address how elements can affect each other with regard to the render layers.

- How does Chrome decide which element to put in which layer?
- How can I find out what was decided in my case? (i.e. debug the render layers)
- How can different elements affect each other with regard to the render layer?
- How can an animation of an element that is in another layer, cause a re-paint of the whole page? (at some cases this happens)
- How can I ensure a fast render of my animation? i.e - force the element into another layer and make sure the animation doesn't cause a re-paint of the entire page.
- And lastly - how can I stay on top of changes to the browser's rendering algorithm so that these problems don't return in the future?

Comment: That's a lot of questions.

Comment: For the first question, this file from Chromium is quite clear and self-explanatory. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/graphics/CompositingReasons.h

Comment: And this one is even better: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/72fef91ac1ef679207f51def8133b336a6f6588f/Source/platform/graphics/CompositingReasons.cpp?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I finally found a solution to my problem.

- This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19710301/319182) explains how to enable the "Layers panel" in chrome DevTools. That panel allows you to see in real time (even during animations) which elements are in which layers on the page.
  Also, each layer has properties that tell you why chrome decided to make a layer out of it.
- Using this tool I was able to determine that one of my elements which is an overlay of the whole page (to mask the page when there's a modal div) sometimes gets its own layer and sometimes not.
- The reason it got a layer only when some other elements like `marquee` were present on the page was that chrome detected that "the element may overlap other composited elements".
  When these "other composited elements" are not there, this overlay element does not get it's own layer. And when I open the modal there's also an animation on the opacity of the overlay div. And since it was not in a separate layer - it caused the entire page to re-paint itself in each frame (this is sometimes referred to as a "paint storm").
- I solved the problem by making sure the overlay div will always get its own layer, by adding [`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/) to the style of this div.